# Using Node and Firebase Together

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have an app that POST an image to a 3rd party API. One of the parameters is an `imageCallbackURL` a webhook callback URL when image is processed.

If I am using Firebase as my backend, could I also create a node server at www.mysite.com/something that their api could POST the edited image to? I'd then have some server side functionality that would store the new image in Firebase storage.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

We just released an [integration between Google Cloud Functions and Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You could use a [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to implement a web hook. We even have an [example of a WebHook in our list of use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis).

The details of course depend on what the third party is sending in the WebHook and what you'd want to do with it in the Cloud Function. If you have a better idea on that, I'd recommend updating your question or posting a new one.